# Modifying the error message from a `stop()` call in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

In my `stop` call below, I get a message that is like:

`Error: cname not found in the 'data'.hhk not found in the 'data'.`

I was wondering if there is a way for the message to look like:

`'cname', 'hhk' not found in the 'data'.`

Is this possible in Base R?

```
vars = c("cname", "hhk")
a = 1
if(a) stop(paste(vars, "not found in the 'data'."))

Current Error message: Error: cname not found in the 'data'.hhk not found in the 'data'.
Desired Error message: 'cname', 'hhk' not found in the 'data'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collapse `vars` into one string :

```
vars = c("cname", "hhk")
a = 1
if(a) stop(paste(toString(vars), "not found in the 'data'."))
#Error: cname, hhk not found in the 'data'.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using two `paste` commands:

```
if(a) stop("'",paste(paste(vars,collapse = "', '",sep = ""), "' not found in the 'data'.",sep = ""))
Error: 'cname', 'hhk' not found in the 'data'.
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `stopifnot`

```
stopifnot(a)
```

---

Or with `glue`

```
if(a) stop(glue::glue("{toString(vars)} not found in the data"))
#Error: cname, hhk not found in the data
```